# Parsing Results Form NLog Network Target

Tags: c#, nlog, udpclient

I am working on creating a client that will be able to view the log messages that NLog is transmitting from a server application. I have the server sending the messages and the client receiving the UDP packets. I am wanting to populate a DataGridView in a WindowsForm (C#), but I am unable to parse the XML-like messages I receive. I would think this would be easy.

The resulting packet looks like this:

```
<log4j:event logger="SERVER.WCFService" level="INFO" timestamp="1446588493487" thread="14"><log4j:message>SAMPLE MESSAGE</log4j:message><log4j:properties><log4j:data name="log4japp" value="SERVER.vshost.exe(12056)" /><log4j:data name="log4jmachinename" value="SERVER" /></log4j:properties></log4j:event>
```

I take the UDP packet and push it into an XmlDocument like so:

```
UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(listenPort);
IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,listenPort);

byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);

XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();

using (var sr = new StringReader(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)))
using (var xtr = new XmlTextReader(sr) { Namespaces = false })
     xd.Load(xtr);
```

I would like to be able to grab the level, timestamp, and message for starters.

Comment: so what's the issue with the code that you have currently pasted..? can you state whether it works etc... have you done a simple google search to see how to parse an XML file or how to read particular node(s) values

Comment: @MethodMan There is nothing wrong with loading the result into an XmlDocument using my code. The problem is getting the values based off of the element's name in the newly created XmlDocument. I've tried many different things to try and get these values as I've done similar stuff with XML before. I've tried Xelement, SelectSingleNode, etc. It almost appears that I have a namespace issue, but I do not know. I figured instead of posting the methods that failed, hopefully someone could point me in the correct direction. I have searched the web for this and came up with nothing.

Comment: can't you use something like `XPath`

Comment: I still can't figure this way out. I changed my NLog target from NLogViewer to Network. I do a string.split() method on the | that is sent in the packet. This works for now...